# Deleting node from LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have this function to remove nodes that matches a certain criteria in the list. Initially when I wrote it, head node was not deleted if `head->value was >= delete_value`, but other nodes in the list were deleted, so I decided to write the last if statement to only delete and amend the list if `head->value was >= delete_value`.
It works, but I'm not sure if this is normal?

```
void remove(List * & head, double value)
{
   if (head == NULL)
   {
    cout << "Empty List";
    return;
   }

   if (head != NULL && head->value != delete_value)
   {
    List* temp1 = head;
    List* temp2 = temp1->next;

       while (temp2 != NULL)
       {
          if (temp2->value >= delete_value)
          {
            List* temp3 = temp2;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
            temp1->next = temp2;
            delete temp3;
          }
          else
          {
            temp1 = temp2;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
          }
       }
   }

   //This deletes head node, if value is greater than or equal to delete_value
   if (head != NULL && head->value >= delete_value)
   {
    List*temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
   }
return;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this should be a member function of the `List` class rather than a standalone function.

Answer (score 2):

I believe these two lines are causing all the trouble.

```
 List* temp1 = head;
 List* temp2 = temp1->next;
```

`temp2` never gets the head node because it is initialized as `head->next` to begin with.

I prefer double pointers since I find them rather cleaner.

```
void remove(Node<ItemType> * & head, double value) {    
    Node<ItemType> **pp = &head;
    Node<ItemType> *curr = head;
    while (curr) {
        if (curr->item == value) {
            *pp = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = *pp;
        }
        else {
            pp = &curr->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this the functionality you are looking for? I'm guessing you are using the STL List here. This will step through the list and remove anything that is greater or equal to the value passed.

```
template<typename T>
void remove(std::list<T> *l, T value) {
    for (auto it = l->begin(); it != l->end();) {
        if (*it <= value) {
            it = l->erase(it);
        }
        else {
            it++;
        }
    }
}
```